# Mongoose Schema User Submitted Date Value

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I am trying to create a product schema with mongoose with a `Expiry Date` field to be submitted by the user.

It is just a date field but it needs to be selected by the user rather than hardcoded to a specific date in advance.

**How can I achieve this?**

Here is my basic model:

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        maxlength: 32
      },
      description: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        maxlength: 20000
      },
      price: {
        type: Number,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        maxlength: 32
      },
      category: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category',
        required: true
      }
    }, {timestamps: true}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a date picker and save its value as an ISO Date string to mongoose.

```
example: const date = new Date().toISOString();
```

Your mongoose Schema will look like this:

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    expirationDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date(), // Set a default date
        required: true, // or you can mark it as required.
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        maxlength: 32
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        maxlength: 20000
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        maxlength: 32
    },
    category: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category',
        required: true
    }
}, { timestamps: true }
);
```